# Write a csv file to a folder in remote computer

Tags: r, ubuntu

I would like to write a csv file to a remote folder in a computer identified by `user@ip-address`, running a different OS (e.g. my current OS is iOS and remote OS is Ubuntu-19).

Below, the straightforward code saves a file in local folder

```
write.csv(1:10, 'Save.csv')
```

But I want to have something like

```
write.csv(1:10, "root@xx.xxx.x.x:/folder/Save.csv")
```

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you separate it into two steps?

1. Save it locally with `write.csv()`
2. Call iOS's equivalent of [scp](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/TransferFiles) (wrapped in R's [`system()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html)) to copy the file to the remote machine.

It would look like

```r
write.csv(1:10, 'Save.csv')

system("scp Save.csv root@xx.xxx.x.x:/folder/Save.csv")
```

Comment: I like how @user1987607's function would replace step 2, once the file is written locally.

Comment: While a direct approach with write.csv() would been perfect, but I accept this approach as good solution.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be possible with the cp.remote function of the ssh-utils package

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ssh.utils/ssh.utils.pdf

A wrapper around the scp shell command that handles local/remote files and allows copying between remote hosts via the local machine.

```r
cp.remote(remote.src, path.src, remote.dest, path.dest, verbose = FALSE,
via.local = FALSE, local.temp.dir = tempdir())
```